# Can i stored iMovie projects and files in an NTFS external drive?

Tags: mac, backup, external-disk, imovie, ntfs

I'm backing up manually my computer with the data I want to keep.

I've already backed up iPhoto library in a a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) partition as [it seems is the only way to store it properly](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24267879#24267879).

They say that it involves other softwares and some internal databases.

I was wondering if it happen the same iMovie or on the other hand, it is just a group of folders and files. (as I believe it is in this case)

Could I use my NTFS external drive to backup iMovie files and folders? (projects and events folders)

I'm using Mac Os X 10.6.8 and I'm updating to Mavericks. 
I'm using Tuxela NTFS to be able to write and read NTFS from my Mac.
I'm using iMovie 11 9.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Since you have Tuxera NTFS installed, you are able to read/write to the drive fine, so iMovie will have no problem saving to it. iMovie projects aren't as complex as iPhoto libraries, so you shouldn't have any problems.